# GPS Navigation Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, navigation, graph-theory

I have thousands of input GPS values from a vehicle that I want to map to specific values given by nodes on a road graph. Take the below image. Each Node (A-F) has information about the previous edge that connects to it (as well as latitude/longitude). I want to match some of this information to each GPS point in my input GPS coordinates.

Road Graph
[image]

So far I am able to do so, but there are some edge cases. Take the image for example, when we reach node B we think we could be on path BCD or path BEF. It isn't until the nodes are far enough apart that we know which route we have taken with the input. This is because roads aren't simply a 2D line. They have width and the vehicle could be on the edge of the road. Determining which road it is on is difficult because we do not know the width of the road. So, when we arrive at node B the vehicle can be between BC or BE. It isn't until later down each path do we know where we are at.

That being said, we can traverse each route until we have only one option and therefore we know we are on that road. We can backfill the data from all the previous nodes on the correct route. I have issues coming up with an algorithm for this, however.

How can I handle this in code? I've thought about doing a DFS at every intersection and figuring out which path has the highest count of edges that contain input points from the vehicle. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would map gps inputs to nodes firstly, but during the maping operation each node should propagate a `count++` to parent node (and detect the cycles if cycles are possible) .You can propagate only up to (but without) intersection point. Than You can just follow the path and on the crossroads take the biggest value and go with that path.

You will end up with something like (for example):

```
0 -> 0 -> 4 -> 3 -> 1
     |
     ---> 2 -> 1 -> 0
```

In second node you will choose 'upper' direction. What is important that you propagate only to point where `parent->numberOfNeighbours > 1` because you always have to reach the crossroad, so no need to propagate this further.

Comment: This may work, but I am curious about what happens if the two roads are parallel and we are uncertain what road we are on for more than one intersection. Do we traverse the graph until we reach an unfeasible length? Or is it unlikely that we can have more than one intersection with which we are still uncertain what road we are on. Imagine the case where we have an off ramp and it leads to an overpass where two roads are on the same direction, but different altitudes. In this case we may have some time before we diverge.

Comment: you should limit checks to some radius, and consider path changes only in this radius, taking into account weights from previous move. More or less if you turn right  (strongest signal) and after you are moving forward, you can build a weight function that will favor the current path until there is not strong enough signal from another parallel path (so longer your current path is - harder to change it to parallel one (as long there is no intersection!). If such signal occurs you change your current path to parallel one (so you can diverge not only on the crossroad but anytime

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding the problem correctly, once you reach node B you have some uncertainty about the path ahead. However, upon reaching either node C or E, the path forward is now known up until the next node with an outdegree greater than one.

Then, I would think you simply keep track of your path until an intersection and list all nodes adjacent to that intersection (similar to BFS). Check against this list of possible nodes and once you reach one add it to the current path. At this point you would know the road you are on and can forecast the path forward until the next intersection, repeating until your destination.

Comment: The issue is, upon reaching node C and E we still do not know which road we are on. Why is this? This is because the road has a width, it isn't a 2D line. If the vehicle is on the road BCD, but close enough to the edge that our algorithm does not know if it is actually on BCD, but rather could be on BEF. As you check the road BEF, we see the vehicle eventually gets too far from BCD (where it is actually), we can then backtrack and take correct road BCD.

Comment: My question is how to implement this properly in code.